# Select multiple values with same ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i am not sure how to retrieve all values with same id and display them in one label.

**Example :**

```
id   food

1     chicken

1     fish
```

**Desired output**:

```
chicken,fish
```

How can i do that?

```
SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
con.Open();
str = "select food from foodName where id= 1";
com = new SqlCommand(str, con);

SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Label1.Text = reader["food"].ToString();
}
con.Close();
```

Comment: Can you share some sample code? Like where are you casting the strings to.

Comment: what do you mean same id?

Comment: Can you atleast show us what you've done so far?

Comment: show me some effort then i can help you

Comment: i have edit the question @ArsalanQaiser

Comment: Label1.Text = reader["food "].ToString(); change this

Comment: still it displays one value @ArsalanQaiser

Comment: because you add a id filter in your query and can you tell me your table structure

Comment: by right it should display fish and chicken as both id is 1. but it only display fish

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Label1.Text = string.Empty;
SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
con.Open();
str = "select food from foodName where id= 1";
com = new SqlCommand(str, con);

SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Label1.Text += reader["food"].ToString();
}
con.Close();
```

Comment: this works if only i want to display. but i need to click on the gridview and display the label. when i did that, the values add up . like when i click id 1 it will give me chicken,fish. when i click id 2, it will give me chicken,fish, fish, prawn. and it keeps adding up @ArsalanQaiser

Comment: e.g: you need this output?
if click on id 1 then output will be chicken,fish
you need if click on id 2 then output will be fish, prawn.
am i right?

Comment: yes. how do i do that? i have been stuck for days. @ArsalanQaiser

Comment: i tried to put Label1.text = string.Empty; but then it displays nothing

Comment: Thank you so much. it works! is there any ways i should put ','? @ArsalanQaiser

Comment: so can i put comma ? @ArsalanQaiser

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a foreach and add form a string using StringBuilder,

```
StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder();
foreach(yourClassname test in yourList)
{
    test.Append(test.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lambda expression in C#.

```
 var list = new List<Product>(){
                new Product {ID=1, FoodName ="chicken"},
                new Product{ID=2, FoodName="egg"},
                new Product{ID=1, FoodName="fish"}
            };

 var output = list.Where(s => s.ID == 1).Select(s=>s.FoodName).ToArray(); //result will be array of items.
```

Use string.Join to get output results "chicken,fish"

```
string.Join(",", output); //result will be chicken,fish
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't provide us your code. I'm assuming you have a list of food [`List<Food>`] and you have an `id` and `foodName` inside of it. What you can do is this:

```
IEnumerable<string> selectedFood = foods.FindAll(food => food.id == 1).Select(food => food.foodName);

string result = string.Join(", ", selectedFood);
```

You can now use the result as your label's value.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to concatenate all values:

```
String chickenVar = "Chicken";
String fishVar = "Fish";

 String result = chickenVar +", " + fishVar;
```